# Solspace Calendar - Issues with surrounding beginning of cal loops with conditionals

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar

We need to tell whether the user has chosen a specific date or has just defaulted to our calendar:

- example.com/calendar
- example.com/calendar/11/31/2013

We're trying the following:

```
{if segment_2 == ""}
  {exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" date_range_end="today" show_days="1" pad_short_weeks="n"}
{if:else}
  {exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="{segment_4}-{segment_2}-{segment_3}" date_range_end="{segment_4}-{segment_2}-{segment_3}" show_days="1" pad_short_weeks="n"}
{/if}
  ... do stuff with the events for the given day here.
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

When we go to the `/calendar` page all of the data returned is fine, however, when we go to a specific date page, the data returned is for the current day (ie the data that's returned on the `/calendar` page).

Does anybody know as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just simple conditionals are parsed before the modules and plugins. Simple ones are the conditionals using just `if` and just early parsed variables. `segment_N` are early parsed variables, but your conditionals have an `if:else`.

So, try this:

```
{if segment_2 == ""}
  {exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" date_range_end="today" show_days="1" pad_short_weeks="n"}
{/if}
{if segment_2}
  {exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="{segment_4}-{segment_2}-{segment_3}" date_range_end="{segment_4}-{segment_2}-{segment_3}" show_days="1" pad_short_weeks="n"}
{/if}
  ... do stuff with the events for the given day here.
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Or this:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
    {if segment_2 == ""}
        date_range_start="today" date_range_end="today"
    {/if}
    {if segment_2}
        date_range_start="{segment_4}-{segment_2}-{segment_3}" date_range_end="{segment_4}-{segment_2}-{segment_3}"
    {/if} 
    show_days="1" 
    pad_short_weeks="n"
}
  ... do stuff with the events for the given day here.
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

[This article about this subject](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/simple-vs-complex-conditionals-in-expressionengine-templates) is really good.

Comment: That was an informative article; and both solutions worked just fine. Thanks for your help.